# Dynamic Query Not Working Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have JPA Spring boot.
I want to dynamic OR AND Query Like "select column from table where condition1 = something1 || condtion2 = something2 ... || conditionN = somethingN"
I use composite Repository.

**OtherRepositoryCustomImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class OtherRepositoryCustomImpl implements OtherRepositoryCustom{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<Person> findUserFromLocus() {
    String query = "select * from Person";
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }

}
```

**OtherRepositoryCustom.java**

```
public interface OtherRepositoryCustom {
    List<Person> findUserFromLocus();
}
```

**OtherRepository.java**

```
public interface OtherRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String>, OtherRepositoryCustom {
    //my function query
}
```

**OtherService.java**

```
@Service
public class OtherService {

@Autowired
private OtherRepository repository;

public List<String> getAllAutosomalKit() {
    return repository.findDistinctAutosomalKit();
}

public List<String> getAllYKit() {
    return repository.findDistinctYKit();
}

public List<String> getAllXKit() {
    return repository.findDistinctXKit();
}

public List<String> getAllLocusAutosom() {
    return repository.findLocusAutosom();
}

public List<String> getAllLocusY() {
    return repository.findLocusY();
}

public List<String> getAllLocusX() {
    return repository.findLocusX();
}

public List<Object[]> getStatsGraph(String locus, String table) {
    if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("Autosom")) {
        return repository.findStatsGraphA(locus);
    } else if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("Y_STRs")) {
        return repository.findStatsGraphY(locus);
    } else if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("X_STRs")) {
        return repository.findStatsGraphX(locus);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

public List<Person> testSearchLocus(){
    return repository.findUserFromLocus();
}
}
```

**and there is Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'otherService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'otherRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.util.List io.forensic.springboot.Kit.OtherRepositoryCustom.findUserFromLocus()! No property findUserFromLocus found for type Person!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.19.RELEASE.jar:1.5.19.RELEASE]
    at io.forensic.springboot.TheRealApiApplication.main(TheRealApiApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'otherService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'otherRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.util.List io.forensic.springboot.Kit.OtherRepositoryCustom.findUserFromLocus()! No property findUserFromLocus found for type Person!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'otherRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.util.List io.forensic.springboot.Kit.OtherRepositoryCustom.findUserFromLocus()! No property findUserFromLocus found for type Person!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.util.List io.forensic.springboot.Kit.OtherRepositoryCustom.findUserFromLocus()! No property findUserFromLocus found for type Person!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:207) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:451) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:223) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) ~[spring-beans-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findUserFromLocus found for type Person!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:336) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:312) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:275) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:246) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.18.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

there are errors at complie time.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM ..." is invalid JPQL. Any JPA docs would tell you that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the causes of errors.
my problem is the class name.
After I changed **OtherRepositoryCustomImpl** To **OtherRepositoryImpl**.
All of the errors are gone.

Change Your class name to the following pattern

**(className).java**

```
public interface (className) extends CrudRepository<Person, String>, (className)Custom {
    //my function query
}
```

**(className)Impl.java**

```
@Service
public class (className)Impl implements (className)Custom{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<Person> findUserFromLocus() {
    String query = "select * from Person";
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }

}
```

**(className)Custom.java**

```
public interface (className)Custom {
    List<Person> findUserFromLocus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you query may be wrong, try replacing it with
`String query = "SELECT p FROM Person p";`

Here article explaining it: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entitymanager